Document Intelligence Studio gives High latency while working on OCR (Handwritten)
We are using Document Intelligence Studio to retrieve data from a pdf. Tried the same thing with API calling uisng python ,It also didnt yield any result
API Version: 2024-02-29(Preview).
Number of pages :17
Type : OCR (Handwritten)
Region: east

I have uploaded my pdf here and waited for 2 minutes, which yielded nothing. How to overcome this issue?

Latency Issue in "prebuilt-document" model

What is the error you getting? provide the sample pdf.

We've received reports from several customers experiencing latency issues in the East US region when using the 2024-02-29-preview API version.
Analysis:
Upon investigation, it seems like there is a capacity problem specific to the 2024-02-29-preview version in the East US region.
Temporary Solutions:
To mitigate the issue temporarily, you can consider utilizing another region or opting for a different API version until we resolve the underlying problem.

Mitigation/Fix Progress:
A solution has been developed and integrated, though it's pending deployment. We're actively prioritizing this task and have escalated the issue to the Product group team. Rest assured, I'll keep you updated on the progress and notify you once the issue is resolved.
